# set all textfields in edit mode if row was selected

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, nstableview, nstextfield

i have a tableview, with 4 columns and in each column is a textfield.
now i would like to realize, that if i select a row all textfields in this row will be in edit mode.

but i don't know how it works.
i work with swift 3 for macOS

Comment: i updated my tags

Comment: What do you mean by "edit mode"? If you want the text fields to be editable, select the text field in IB and switch Behaviour to Editable.

Comment: ahh okay :) thx !